# How can I see the Unity changelog

Tags: 11.10, unity

Right now I am using the 4.24.0 version of Unity but I heard a 5.x version was released. Where can I see the changelog for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sort of related to your other question, but FWIW, changleog is here :

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity/trunk/view/head:/ChangeLog